# uploadify progress bar only updates two times?

Tags: actionscript-3, uploadify

I am using uploadify in a project and I threw a console.log statement in my onProgress callback...  It seems to only be executed when starting the upload, and when completing the upload.  Even with a very large file upload, that is the behavior I get.

The progress bar is based off of Flash sending data, not off of the server-side reporting back what it's received..  So I am a bit confused as to why this isn't working...

The actionscript is doing:

```
file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, fileProgressHandler);
```

and so I did a simple experiment by putting in the fileProgressHandler method:

```
ExternalInterface.call('console.log("percentage: ' + percentage + ' - startTimer: ' + startTimer + ' - getTimer: ' + getTimer() + '")');
```

and when uploading I file, I see immediately:
50%
100%

and then a big long pause while the file is uploading...  Then onAllComplete gets hit....  So, it's apparent that the actual upload progress is inaccurate, and I am very curious as to why.  Does anyone have any ideas?

I am wondering if this is somehow related to me running my app in development mode on localhost, and if it were hosted on a real server if the result would be different..  But I have no way of knowing that.

-patrick

Comment: The idea that running locally is causing this is most likely not the case, since when you run a SWF off a server, the SWF is simply downloaded and then run within the local domain of the user anyway. Were that not true, a lot of security infrastructure in flash would be completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

> But I have no way of knowing that.

You do actually.
This most-likely sounds like an issue with it being on localhost.
Get your stuff off localhost and onto a server.
Download and install FireFox
Install flash player debug for FireFox
There should be a Flash console tab you will probably have to enable it
You can look at your trace statements in the log file.